# group loop for the data

Tags: python, loops

I have 10000 observation and each 10 observation indicated different group.Hypothetically we can say that first ten group A, and then 11-20th is B till end of the data. I need to multiply each observation of the group by same coefficients such as first observation of the each group by 0.01, second observation of the each group by 0.02, til last observation(10th) by 0.10. 
How can I create a loop for this system. I am so sorry ask this silly question but I really need help. Please could you provide me python code for this loop?

Comment: Please add your attempts before just asking for code here

Comment: to be honest I am absolete beginner thats why I ask this silly question. I know for this platform it is really in appropriate but if you could help me about it I would really appriciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
arr = [i for i in range(100)] #replace arr with your array of size 100000
coefficients = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5] # This is the list of 10 or so coefficients
sizeOfGroup = len(coefficients) # assuming that you'll have as many coefficients as the size of each group
for (index, value) in enumerate(arr):
    arr[index] *= coefficients[index % sizeOfGroup]

print(arr)
```